# Possible to login to Facebook without the JS, PHP or native device API (handle all via HTTP[S])?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an app that uses no code... it's a declarative workflow. I can't use any of the three methods they outline on their site ([https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/))... instead I have to do it 100% custom (calling a service, parsing the response for the OAuth token, including it on future HTTP GETs & POSTs...

Effectively I'm trying to write something that will add an entry to a company Facebook PAGE object without requiring a login dialog... I want it to do this automatically, maybe this means as an app...

Can't find anything on their site that shows how to do this... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... I needed to login as an app as outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/